# The double factorial notation

Tags: soft-question, notation

The double factorial is defined as
$$n!! = \begin{cases} n \cdot (n-2) \cdot (n-4) \cdots 3 \cdot 1 = \dfrac{(n+1)!}{2^{(n+1)/2}((n+1)/2)!} & \text{ If $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, is odd}\\
n \cdot (n-2) \cdot (n-4) \cdots 4 \cdot 2 = 2^{n/2} (n/2)! & \text{ If $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, is even}\\
1 & \text{If $n \in \{0,-1\}$}
\end{cases} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (\star)$$
I am curious about the origin of this notation. I see it to be a poor, non-suggestive notation. After a quick search, [I see that the notation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) was first used in [Arfken $1985$](http://books.google.com/books?id=JOpHkJF-qcwC&q=double%20factorial#v=snippet&q=double%20factorial&f=false). I am curious as to why one would use such a non-suggestive notation, call it double factorial and more importantly, why have others caught on to this notation? Also, are there alternate notations to denote $(\star)$?

Comment: Curious question. When you look at the references on [*MathWorld*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html), they mention Meserve, B. E. "Double Factorials from 1948. Also, you can see it on [*OIES*](http://oeis.org/A006882). Additionally, we get into [*Multi Factorial*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multifactorial.html).

Comment: Evidently there is a multifactorial symbol $n!^{(k)}$, e.g. double factorial is $n!^{(2)}$.  According to wikipedia some people are trying to popularize the use of $n!_k$ instead (without much success).

Comment: @Amzoti Oh, I see. I missed that citation on mathworld. Thanks. However, I have not been able to track down the $1948$ article.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber The notation $n!_{k}$ seems to make sense and is at the least better than the multi-factorial notation.

Comment: @Marvis I also cannot track down the article on the web (yet), but I did find this reference [*See 2.4.1*](http://dare2.ubvu.vu.nl/bitstream/handle/1871/24227/sensitivitygaussian.pdf?sequence=2). For k-odd, Meserve defined Double factorial by: $$k!! = k \cdot (k-2)\cdot\cdot\cdot3\cdot 1$$ Of course, I'd still like to see the paper. You are an excellent resource by the way, I truly admire your abilities! Regards

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks!

Comment: @Marvis Sure, I like it better too.  $n!_2$ comes off pretty slick.

Comment: I've always thought this notation is sub-optimal because it looks like an iterated factorial---a factorial of a factorial.

Comment: I personally think the notation is fine (perhaps because I learned it too long ago). The operation is related to factorial and the operation is more commonly encountered than $(n!)!$. I think of it as the "every other" factorial. Interesting question. (+1)

Comment: Continuing along the lines of "every other" factorial, I first encountered the notation in the context of perfect matchings. A complete graph on $n+1$ vertices ($n+1$ even) has $n!!$ perfect matchings. Choosing an arbitrary vertex as "1", there are $n$ other vertices to pair it with. Now we have a complete graph on $n-1$ vertices, which has $(n-2)!!$ perfect matchings by induction. Therefore, the original graph has $n(n-2)!! = n!!$ perfect matchings. (Every choice we make knocks out two vertices, hence the "every other" aspect.)

Comment: Just thought I'd add my 2 cents and contribute that an alternate definition of the double factorial function is $x!!=2^{\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\left(1-\cos\left(\pi x\right)\right)\right)}\cdot\pi^{\left(\frac{1}{4}\left(\cos\left(\pi x\right)-1\right)\right)}\cdot\frac{2\left(\frac{x+2}{2}\right)!}{x+2}$ for integer values of $x$ equal to or greater than $-1$, or $x!!=2^{\left(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\left(1-\cos\left(\pi x\right)\right)\right)}\cdot\pi^{\left(\frac{1}{4}\left(\cos\left(\pi x\right)-1\right)\right)}\cdot \Gamma(\frac{x}{2}+1)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 6):

Well, the way I assume it was chosen was:

> With one factorial sign, we decrement by one:
>
> $n! = n \cdot (n - 1) \cdot ... \cdot 2 \cdot 1$
>
> So, if we have *two* factorial signs, let's decrement by *two*!
>
> $n!! = n \cdot (n - 2) \cdot ... \cdot 3 \cdot 1$

And thus, it was done.

It's a terrible abuse of notation, as mentioned in the other answer, I'll agree.

Answer (score 5):

The way I parse it, $n!$ is a post-fix function call. Therefore $n!!$ parses as
`factorial(factorial(n))`.  This notation has my disapprobation.

Comment: I think this should be a comment.

Comment: It solicits opinions on notation, so I see it as reasonable to post this as an answer.  I am addressing the question directly, which is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @ncmathsadist except that the question explicitly asks for "the origin of this notation" and "why one would use such a non-suggestive notation".