# What does the !! mean in trigonometric identity?

Tags: notation, factorial

What does the $!!$ mean in:

$$
\int_0^x \sin^n(t) \mathrm dt = \begin{cases}
\frac{(n-1)\color{red}{!!}}{n\color{red}{!!}}\Big[1-\cos(x)\sum_{j=0}^{(n-1)/2}\frac{(2j-1)\color{red}{!!}}{(2j)\color{red}{!!}}\sin^{2j}(x)\Big]&\text{for $n$ odd}\\
\frac{(n-1)\color{red}{!!}}{n\color{red}{!!}}\Big[x-\cos(x)\sum_{j=0}^{(n-2)/2}\frac{(2j)\color{red}{!!}}{(2j+1)\color{red}{!!}}\sin^{2j+1}(x)\Big]&\text{for $n$ even}\\
\end{cases}.
$$

Is it factorial applied twice?

This is from page 317 of *An Atlas of Functions*, Second edition: with Equator, the Atlas Function Calculator by Keith B. Oldham, Jan Myland, Jerome Spanier

Comment: That looks like being the [double-factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html). It's smaller than the factorial: every *other* number multiplied together, not every number multiplied together.

Comment: @Patrick Stevens thanks I'll look it up and try to apply.

Comment: This is not quite a duplicate of [The double factorial notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/269450/26369)

Comment: actually there is a symbolic index in that book on page 733 where it is described as double factorial function [2:13] which is on page 25 where the function is fully explained!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In mathematics, the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) or [semifactorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) of a number $n$ (denoted by $n!!$) is the product of all the integers from $1$ up to $n$ that have the same parity (odd or even) as $n$.

**Example:** $9!! = 9 \cdot 7 \cdot 5 \cdot 3 \cdot 1$

Answer (score 0):

to supplement N3buchadnezzar, some ways to work out the double factorial or semifactorial are as follows:

[image: definition]

following this definition, these handy relations can be used

for even !!

[image: even]

and odd !!

[image]